# How to use AngularJS to invoke executable jar

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services

I intend to create an AngularJS front end that will:

1. Collect user input using an `<input ng-model>` element
2. Invoke an executable jar file using a `<button ng-click>`
3. Publish results of the executable back to front end --> I imagine this is a service pulled from a flat file or DB

I have already built the executable jar file (my engine).

My question -- How do you run the executable jar file from the front-end (Step 2)? Is this basically an http GET?

I'm surprised I can't find examples/solutions to this question anywhere. Is this not an appropriate architecture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need whats called cgi-bin scripts which purpose is to execute script as web page. Script can be bash, python, perl or anything.

In your case, you can follow [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223318/writing-cgi-script-in-java) to execute your .jar.
The cgi-bin script itself is a bash command executing the jar.

This would be a bit easier if you use linux for your server.

Comment: Thank you pltrdy. I can see how that may be a solution. I'm currently exploring building an app in Spring Tool Suite to integrate my java application with an angularjs front end. The Java application is an analytics engine for machine learning, hence the original data science tag...was trying to attract someone in that space who may have run into a similar problem -- have an engine, need to share a front end. Looking to AngularJS as solution.

Comment: OK, This wont be an easy task as your setup is quite specific. I don't know Spring Tool. Can't you just go into cgi-bin + angular implementation?